# Удалить повторения ID более 3-х раз?

Tags: excel, vba

Есть таблица в 50 000 записей, в несколько колонок. 1 и 2 колонки - это ID и дата (запись прихода клиентов за определенное количество лет).

Как можно удалить более ранние записи клиентов, когда они приходили более 3-х раз? Кто-то приходил 1 раз, кто-то 10. Нужно, что бы остались все записи тех, кто приходил 3 или менее 3-х. раз, остальные удалить.

Чтобы было понятнее, пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно,удалить нужно полностью строку с записью, когда визит 4-й и более.

Comment: @vikttur готово.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub DelRepeats2()
Dim aData()
Dim rDel As Range
Dim i As Long, k As Long, n As Long
Const lRepeat As Long = 2 ' макс значение повторов'
    With ActiveSheet ' если нужно, указать другой лист'
        i = .Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row: If i < 2 Then Exit Sub
        aData = .Range("A1:A" & i).Value

        For i = UBound(aData) To 2 Step -1
            n = 0

            For k = i To 2 Step -1
                If aData(k, 1) <> Empty Then
                    If aData(k, 1) = aData(i, 1) Then
                        n = n + 1

                        If n > lRepeat Then
                            aData(k, 1) = Empty

                            If rDel Is Nothing Then
                                Set rDel = .Cells(k, 1)
                            Else
                                Set rDel = Union(rDel, .Cells(k, 1))
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            Next k
        Next i
    End With

    If Not rDel Is Nothing Then rDel.EntireRow.Delete
    Set rDel = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное еще раз, надеюсь отвлек в последний раз. Еще раз, рекомендую добавить еще реквизиты пайпала. Часто хочу отблагодарить за потраченное время на меня, а возможности нету, так как мало кто указывает пайпал.